# Project only a certain field (which is an array) in a find() operation and in the same time only get the first 3 elements from that array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How can I project only a certain field (which is an array) in a find() operation and in the same time only get the first 3 elements from that array?

something like the following :
db.test.find({}, {products: 1, products: {$slice :3}})

"products: 1"  to return only the products in the results
"products: {$slice :3}" to get the first 3 products from the array

Apparently i can either get all the fields of the document with the array sliced, or get only the projects but with all the elements of the array. I cant do both in the same time.

mongodb version:  3.2

Answer (score 0):

If I catch you correctly, here is my test, please correct me if anything I missing.

```
> db.test.find({})

{ "_id" : ObjectId("56c70b588543cbc57664541d"), 
  "attr1": "val1",
  "attr2": "val2",
  "products" : [ 
                { "id" : 1, "name" : "apple" }, 
                { "id" : 2, "name" : "banana" }, 
                { "id" : 3, "name" : "pear" }, 
                { "id" : 4, "name" : "uu" } ] }

> db.test.find({}, {products: 1, products: {$slice: 2}, attr1: 0, attr2: 0})

{ "_id" : ObjectId("56c70b588543cbc57664541d"), 
  "products" : [ { "id" : 1, "name" : "apple" }, 
                 { "id" : 2, "name" : "banana" } ] }
```

It seems `db.test.find({}, {products: 1, products: {$slice :3}, attr1: 0, attr2: 0})` could work well as you mentioned.

---

Another way could be done through [`$slice` in aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/).

```
> db.te.aggregate([{$project: {products: {$slice: ['$products', 0, 2]}}}])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56c70b588543cbc57664541d"), 
  "products" : [ { "id" : 1, "name" : "apple" }, 
                 { "id" : 2, "name" : "banana" } ] }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The missing point is that the the collection does not only have products but other attributes too which i do not want to be returned. ie  { "_id" : ObjectId("1"),   "products" : [ ..], "attr1" : {}, "attr2" :{} .,.. attrN :{} }. In that case the other attributes are also returned.

Comment: @Pitelk, to remove `attr1`... could be done by set `{attr1: 0}`, please refer to my update answer...